# Building a contribution functionality in django (i do not necessarily need the code just an idea)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**NOTE** I am not necessarily asking for code to build this, just ideas on how to do this. Links and blog posts for pointers are welcome.

I am building a rest api.

I have a model

```
class Showcase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Showcases")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to build a functionality where the user that created a showcase can add users that contributed to the project which is the showcase. I was thinking of making this its own model like this:

```
class Collaborator(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Showcase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborated_showcases")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="showcase_owner")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborators")
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="creative_type")
    role = models.TextField(null=True)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.name} collaborated on {self.post.name}"
```

The user would have to search for users and then add them as a contributor to the showcase, which is where my brain scrambles a bit.

The other important thing is that I want to be able to randomly go to a user and get ALL the showcases he has contributed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, this structure works fine for your use case, though:

- models should always be in singular case (`Collaborator`)
- `related_name`s should be lower case (`related_name="showcases"`)
- and I prefer to explicitly spell out all related_names, so I'd add

  - `Collaborator.post` related name `collaborated_showcases`
  - `Collaborator.user` related name `collaborators`
  - `Showcase.user` related_name `owned_showcases`

Then,

- To find an user's owned showcases, `Showcase.objects.filter(user=user)`
- To find an user's collaborated showcases, `Showcase.objects.filter(collaborators=user)` (I think)

I'd suggest having a `Collaborator` object for the owner user as well, so you can show their role more easily as well as make these queries simpler.

Comment: thanks, man, I understand everything except for the last sentence which is having a collaborator object for the owner.

Comment: I just updated the collaborator model, is this edit what you meant?

Comment: No, all I meant was that whether or not some user is the owner of a Showcase, they should also have an associated Collaborator object :)